# Django Apache Site Loads Forever

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Django Site running on an Apache server which is running with no errors but when i serach for localhost it loads forever and doesn't give a 404 response or anything. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Also, i am doing this using Apache and mod_wsgi.

**httpd.conf**

```
Define SRVROOT "c:/Apache24"

ServerName localhost

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

LoadFile "c:/users/administrator/appdata/local/programs/python/python39/python39.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/administrator/appdata/local/programs/python/python39/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp39-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/administrator/appdata/local/programs/python/python39"
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName localhost

ServerAlias localhost

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/myapp/myapp/wsgi_windows.py"

<Directory "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/myapp/myapp/">

    <Files wsgi_windows.py>

        Require all granted

    </Files>

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**wsgi_windows.py**

```
import os

import sys

import site

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/myapp/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who gets a similar problem in the future, i used `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` which i found out about [here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/251) and it now works.